# Probability and counting assignment

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this assignment I am almost done but I am not sure if it is correct.
As of right now I am a little second guessing myself on whether or not the Venn diagram is right.
I also don't know what P([image]A union B) would be in part (c).

Comment: $A\cup B = P (A)+P(B)-(A\Cap B)$ and $P (A\Cap B) $ is the middle part of your venn diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is all good.

For c), note that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(A^C \cap B) = 0.41+0.17=0.58$

So, that means that the percentage of all Canadians who did not receive a flu shot in either year is $1-P(A \cup B) = 1-0.58=0.42$

Comment: How come for this question $$P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(A^C∩B)$$ when$$P(A∪B)$$ can also be $$P(A∪B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B)?$$

Comment: @j.law Because $P(A \cap B) + P(A^C \cap B) = P(B)$. That is, all Canadians receiving a shot in 2014 equals all Canadians receiving a shot in 2014 and in 2012 plus all Canadians redeicing a shot in 2014 but not in 2012. Therefore, $P(B)-P(A \cap B)=P(A^C \cap B)$. And now you see that the equations match.

Answer (score 2):

The Venn diagram is *okay*, as the notes make it clear that the $41\%$ and $44\%$ apply to their entire sets, not just the parts they are written inside.

For added clarity I rather suggest writing the totals for the entire area on the borders and instead placing $14\%$ and $17\%$ inside those areas (being $41-27$ and $44-27$ respectively).

Then you would clearly see that $\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement) ~=~ 100\%-(14+27+17)\% ~=~ 42\%$